# Partial node list returned in RunDeck 2.5

Tags: rundeck

We just recently upgraded our RunDeck host to v2.5.0-1 and I've noticed something rather annoying. When I search for nodes, only the first 20 matches are visible even though the total number of matches are shown. The previous version had the option to show the "next 20" or "show remaining" but that option isn't available.

Does anyone know if there's a setting I may be missing somewhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug was created [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1208) regarding this issue. Another(!) upgrade should address this. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.